# Configuring an offscreen framebuffer fails the completeness test

Tags: iphone, opengl-es

I'm trying to create an offscreen framebuffer into which I can do some OpenGL drawing, and then pull the bits out manually.  I'm following the instructions [here](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/WorkingwithEAGLContexts/WorkingwithEAGLContexts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008793-CH103-SW6), but in step 4, status is 0 instead of GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE_OES.

If I insert a call to glGetError() after every gl call, it returns 0 (GL_NO_ERROR) every time.  But, the values of variables do not change during the call.  E.g.,

```
GLuint framebuffer;
glGenFramebuffersOES(1, &framebuffer);
glBindFramebufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, framebuffer);
```

the value of framebuffer does not get altered at all (even when I change it to some arbitrary value and re-execute).  It's almost like the gl calls are not actually being made.  I'm linking against OpenGLES framework, and get no compile, link, or run-time errors (or warnings).

I'm at a loss as to what to do next.  I've tried continuing on with my drawing, but do not see the results I expect, but at this point I can't tell whether it's because of the above error, or the conversion to a UIImage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like you don't have an active GL context when you try to create the FBO.

Edit: For the sake of completeness, here's [how to create an OpenGL ES 1.1 context](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/DeterminingOpenGLESCapabilities/DeterminingOpenGLESCapabilities.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008793-CH102-SW7) and activate it:

```
EAGLContext* myContext = [[EAGLContext alloc] initWithAPI:kEAGLRenderingAPIOpenGLES1];
[EAGLContext setCurrentContext: myContext];
```

Comment: Can you elaborate?  I thought creating the FBO was what was giving me the GL context for me to draw into.

Yes, I am an OpenGL newbie.

Comment: Never mind...I figured out what you meant, and yes, that was indeed the problem.  Now to figure out why the end result is all black.  Thanks.